# Raster Calculator for PyQgis

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator

I'm trying to process two raster on the Raster Calculator of PyQgis and I wrote a script, but QGis 3.2 crashes everytime I run the script.

```py
import processing
import os
import time
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
folder="C:/++ELABORAZIONI_NUOVE/entrevistas/PUNTOS_ENTREVISTA_PROVA/mask/"
filelist=os.listdir(folder)
entries=[]
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
for file in filelist:
    if file.endswith('.tif'):
        layer=QgsRasterLayer('C:/++ELABORAZIONI_NUOVE/entrevistas/PUNTOS_ENTREVISTA_PROVA/mask/','layer')
        lyr=QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        lyr.ref=layer.name()+'@1'
        lyr.raster=layer
        lyr.bandNumber=1
        entries.append(lyr)
        comarca=QgsRasterLayer('C:/++ELABORAZIONI_NUOVE/expert_panel/comarca_alt_emporda.tif','comarca')
        cmc=QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        cmc.ref=comarca.name()+'@1'
        cmc.raster=comarca
        cmc.banNumber=1
        entries.append(cmc)
        expression='(('+ entries[1].ref +') = 1)*('+ entries[0].ref +')' +'+ ((('+entries[1].ref+') = 0) - 999)'
        print (expression)
        folder2='C:/++ELABORAZIONI_NUOVE/entrevistas/PUNTOS_ENTREVISTA_PROVA/CALC/'
        calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression, folder2 + file, 'GTiff', layer.extent(), layer.width(), layer.height(), entries )
        calc.processCalculation()
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @EnricaGarau! Do you know which line cause the crash? Also, your `layer` only references a directory, not an actual .tif file.